# Como puedo pasar esto a una expresion lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Quiero hacer esto en un codigo que solo ocupa una linea, quien pueda ayudarme seria genial.

```
long processSize = 0;
Process bProcess = null;
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(name).Where(x => x.PagedMemorySize64 > processSize))
{
    processSize = process.PagedMemorySize64;
    bProcess = process;
}

FindProcess.Invoke(null, new ProcessEventArgs(bProcess));
```

Comment: no queda claro el codigo que estas implementando, veo un foreach pero asignas esto a variables simples lo cual esta pisando el valor previo que se haya asignado, no deberias teer una lista de processSize ? porque no es un unico proceso el que recuperas sino que son varios

Comment: Si, es un único proceso el que quiero, teóricamente el mas pesado de todos.
Antes tenia esto:

FindProcess.Invoke(null, new ProcessEventArgs(Process.GetProcessesByName(name).ToArray().Where(process => 
            process.PagedMemorySize64 > processSize).Last()));

El problema es que necesito asignarle a processSize el PagedMemorySize64 de cada objeto analizado y no se como hacerlo con lambda.

El algoritmo trata de conseguir el proceso mas pesado y retornarlo, lo logre con foreach pero me gustaria lograrlo con Lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas para marcar

- el metodo GetProcessesByName() ya devuelve un array no necesitas usar el ToArray()
- estas ejecutando el GetProcessesByName() dos veces lo cual es poco performente

No aconsejaria realizarlo en una linea porque el codigo queda horrible, inmantenible y poco claro, pero si podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName(name);

Process p = processList.OrderByDescending(process => process.PagedMemorySize64).First();

FindProcess.Invoke(null, new ProcessEventArgs(p));
```

separar el codigo en varias linea no es incorrecto

Comment: Gracias Tuttini!